# How to make an underline animation from the middle if margin:0 auto are not working?

Tags: css

when hovering over a menu item i am doing an animated underline by creating a pseudo class. but the underline is left to right and I wanted to make the stripe appear from the middle. I don't understand why margin: 0 auto didn't work. If it need, I worked with bootstrap 5 beta2.

```
 <style>
    .menu__list {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*margin-bottom: 36px;*/
}

.menu__item {
    position: relative;
}

.menu__item a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu__item:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background: #9a9a9f;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
}

.menu__item:hover:after {
    width: 140%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

</style>
<nav class="menu">
                    <ul class="menu__list d-flex">
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a href="#main">
                                Main
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a href="features">
                                Features
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a href="gallery">
                                Gallery
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a href="team">
                                Team
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a href="#">
                                Contacts
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Comment: sorry if you don't understand something it's my first question and my English so bad. If you need more information, tell me, or I will try to make a snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the underline animation for your `<a>` tags to start from the middle instead of going from left to right. You can utilize the `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements to create a nice animation that starts from the middle and transitions outwards. Try this out.

```css
.menu__list {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*margin-bottom: 36px;*/
}

ul li {
  margin: .75rem auto;
}

.menu__item > a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu__item > a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.menu__item > a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu__item > a:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu__list d-flex">
      <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#main">
              Main
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="features">
              Features
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="gallery">
              Gallery
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="team">
              Team
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#">
              Contacts
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @KonstantinAleksandrov This will make the underline animation start from the middle and transition to each side of the link instead of going left to right. Did you want the links in the center of the page with the underline animation taking up 100% of the page as well? That part wasn't clear for me.

Comment: Well, I already used pseudo class, but I didn't use transform and visibility atributes. whatewer, i tried your method, and that worked much better, but still not correctly. animation was started left but at 15% to right and tried to start from the middle. Few days ago I realized this animation on other project and I just toke margin:0 auto for pseudo element. what happened here I don't know.

Comment: empirically, I understood that this problem arose due to the presence of the modifier postion, so know i'm trying to understand why your method is working) thank you.

Comment: @KonstantinAleksandrov Your welcome! Best of luck.